# Cannot Center Nav and wrong width showing

Tags: html, css

So this is eating the life out of me and I simply cannot figure it out. PLEASE HELP!
I cannot get the menu to sit in the centre or even appear in the 960 width of the parent div. Here is the html and CSS

```
</head>

    <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="logo"> <img src="images/logo.png"></div>
                        <div id="contact"> Tel: 011 234 5678<br>
                                            E-mail: info@domain.co.za</div>
                            <div id="secure">We accept the following via PayFast<img src="images/secure.png"></div>
                                <div id="nav">
                                <ul class="navbars">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Information</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Accreditations</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Electricity Savings</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Colour Temp</a></li>
            </ul>         
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">LED downlights</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">LED strip lights</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">LED floodlights</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Power Supplies</a></li>
            </ul>         
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Online Shopping</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
                                </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="images/slide1.png" alt="" />
<a href="#"><img src="images/slide2.png" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
<img src="images/slide3.png" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
<img src="images/slide4.png" alt="" />
```

```
                        <div id="bulbshow"><img src="images/bulbshow.jpg"></div>
                                    <div id="secure2">We accept the following via PayFast<img src="images/secure.png"></div>


                <div id="footer">© Copyright 2014. All Rights Reserved, Company CC. Website designed and developed by <a href="http://www.domain.co.za"><img class="gi" src="images/gifavicon.png"></a><br>Reproduction in any form without express permission is prohibited.</div>

            </div>

</body>
    </html>



    html {
    background-image: url(../images/tile.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

a:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #e5e61d;
}
    a:active {
    background: #27428a;
}

#container {
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
}

#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width:20%;
    float: left;
}

#contact {
    display: block;
    width:80%
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

#secure {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-bottom: 2%;

}

#nav {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 940px;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 0 ; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
    margin-right:0;
    z-index: 99; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
    position: relative; 



}
ul.navbars {
width:960px;
}

.navbars    {
    height: 30px;
    width:960px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border-right: 0px solid #54879d; 
    }

.navbars li     {
            height: auto;
            width: 160px;  /* Each menu item is 150px wide */
            float: left;  /* This lines up the menu items horizontally */
            text-align: center;  /* All text is placed in the center of the box */
            list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
            font: normal 15px "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif, "Lucida Sans Unicode"; 
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0063d3, #27428a); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#0063d3, #27428a); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0063d3, #27428a); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#0063d3, #27428a); /* Standard syntax */
                        }

.navbars a  {                           
        padding: 18px 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered vertically */
        border-left: 1px solid #54879d; /* Creates a border in a slightly lighter shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the right border, this creates a nice effect. */
        border-right: 1px solid #1f5065; /* Creates a border in a slightly darker shade of blue than the background.  Combined with the left border, this creates a nice effect. */
        text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
        color: white; /* Text color is white */
        display: block;
        }

.navbars li:hover, a:hover {background:#8080B5;
    } 

.navbars li ul  {
        display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
        height: auto;                                   
        margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
        padding: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */         
        }               

.navbars li:hover ul    {
                        display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
                        }
 .navbars li ul li {background-color: #54879d;} 

 .navbars li ul li a    {
        border-left: 1px solid #1f5065; 
        border-right: 1px solid #1f5065; 
        border-top: 1px solid #74a3b7; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #1f5065; 
        }

.navbars li ul li a:hover   {background-color: #00006B;}




#bulbshow {

}

#secure2 {
    text-align: right;
}

#footer {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0063d3, #27428a); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#0063d3, #27428a); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0063d3, #27428a); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#0063d3, #27428a); /* Standard syntax */
    font-size: small;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif, "Lucida Sans Unicode";
    height: 100%;
}

.gi {
    width:2em;
}
```

Comment: This is just HTML, which doesn't help. Also a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help too!

Comment: Please forgive me, I am quite new to all this... here is the fiddle?http://jsfiddle.net/46M3x/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a div in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to center a div, two of them are:

[**Using auto margins**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5ea8/):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Nav"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #444444;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Nav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[**Using absolute margins**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5ea8/1/):

**HTML (is the same)**

**CSS**:

```
#Container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #444444;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Nav {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

As you can see, you can't center a div vertically using `auto` top and bottom margins, so if you want to center your div vertically, you have to make a substraction, and add ½ of it to the top `margin`, for example.

Another approach (and not so recommended) is setting the inner div's display atribute to `inline-block` and setting the container's `text-align` attribute to `center`. Like this:

[**Inline block techique**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5ea8/3/):

```
#Container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #444444;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

#Nav {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

This effectively breaks the margin-top setting, so you couldn't center your div vertically. In this case, you may want to set the parent's `vertical-align` attribute to `middle`, but you should also set its display attribute to `table` and the child's display attribute to `table-cell`, since this only works with tables and div-tables.

**Update**:

You may as well have to check the padding and margin values for your `div`, `ul` and `li` elements, since most browsers provide them with default values. Make sure they're set to `0px` if you want to get rid of undesired spaces;

Comment: I am probably missing the point here. Could you make it work in the fiddle?    http://jsfiddle.net/46M3x/

Comment: Could you please provide a simplified version of your fiddle? with only the essential parts of your problem. It's hard to debug other people's code since I don't even know what you want to achieve (other than a centered div).

Comment: The "container" has an overall width of 960px as seen. The problem is, the nav seems to be running a few pixels outside this. If you compare the position of the nav in relation to the footer, you will see the nav is slightly more to the right

Comment: Please remove everything but your nav and your reference bar from your fiddle, and please correct your indentation.

Comment: Sorry Ariel. Done and Done. You will now be able to see in the result what the problem is with the nav

Comment: You're missing the point of **simplified version** , it's still a copy-paste of your code. Maybe while cleaning up your code you stumble upon the solution to your problem. Please refer to this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok I left only the Nav, Footer and its related CSS   http://jsfiddle.net/46M3x/3/

Comment: Check your `padding` values. They should be `0px` for the `ul` and the `li` elements.

Comment: Are you sure? do you manually set the padding to `0px 0px 0px 0px;` for `li` and `ul`. Because they have values set by default.

Comment: Aha! I didn't have that set on the #navbar. Thank you! I wasn't even aware of default values. Thanks again!

Comment: Just put that comment on a separate response so I can mark as answered. Many thanks!